# Unable to Retrieve Firebase image in imageview

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to make an app where uer can select an image from gallery on button click and after image selected it should be saved on firebase and then retrieve back in my activity. The problem is I have successfully saved image on my firebase database but when my app launches it is not showing image in my ImageView.

Below is my java code. What I am doing wrong please help me

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
String imgDecodableString;
Firebase ref;
ImageView imgView;
String encodedImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     ref = new Firebase("https://setfireimage.firebaseio.com");

      imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);

    byte[] dec = Base64.decode(encodedImage,Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodeByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(dec,0,dec.length);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(decodeByte);


}

public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
    // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    try{
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();



            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
            byte[] byteArray =  baos.toByteArray();
            String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray,Base64.DEFAULT);

                ref.push().setValue(encodedImage, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {

                        if(firebaseError != null){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),firebaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

   }
}
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="random.setimagefirebase.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ImageView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:onClick="loadImagefromGallery"
    android:text="Load Picture" >
</Button>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you have to call this method loadImagefromGallery  in onResume also,also check the resultCode are you getting OK

Comment: I can't see where are you using firebase to retrieve image, i can only see where you're using it to upload it

Comment: In my OnCreate method i ma retrieving images using:                                       `byte[] dec = Base64.decode(encodedImage,Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodeBytBitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(dec,0,dec.length);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(decodeByte);`

Comment: You're retrieving it by using byte[] dec = Base64.decode(encodedImage,Base64.DEFAULT);. But encodedImage value will clear after every launch

Comment: How i can remove this error please help me with possible working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you want to do is something like this:

create a constant in your `Activity` which will correspond for child name of this image:

```
private final String IMAGE = "image";
```

Then, in your `onCreate` you need to do something like this:

```
ref.child(IMAGE).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String data = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            if(data != null) {
                byte[] dec = Base64.decode(data,Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap decodeByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(dec,0,dec.length);
                imgView.setImageBitmap(decodeByte);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

And when you're creating this value in `FireBase` you'll need to do it like this:

```
 mFirebaseRef.child(IMAGE).setValue(encodedImage, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {

            if(firebaseError != null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),firebaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

instead of

```
ref.push().setValue(encodedImage, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {

                        if(firebaseError != null){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),firebaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Image Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

So, when you'll change it, it will automatically call `onDataChanged` in your `onCreate`

Comment: Can i accomplish the same task using getters and setters method.

Comment: i can't quite understand you, if you won't use valueEventListener like i show above, i can't see the way your app will work after relaunch, you see, all of your variables are local and will be cleared, and also, it's the main functionality of firebase, to be informed instantly after some child changed, via valueEventListener, so either i do not understand you, or you do not understand Firebase, and why are you using it

Comment: What if i make a POJO class having getters and setters method to save images at firebase then in Firebase recycler adapter i retrieve them using getters.

Comment: I think it will be ok if you had a lot of images and also using Firebase specific adapter as provided in tutorials, then yes, but what i can see here, it's just one image, so there is no point in creating adapter

Comment: Hey thanks, for single image that worked for me.But when i am using push() to save image then why my app is closing unfortunately and showing error in   String data = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

Comment: Why are you using push() ? I guess there is no need, setValue for child will do the trick, see my save to DB, which i've provided in answer

Comment: Now got it...is there any way to change the image directly from firebase in app like any other string .

Comment: Any name you like(when you using .child it receives String as a paramater), you can simply change child(IMAGE) to child("any string you want")

Comment: How can i get images using getter method in firebase List Adapter.

Comment: I guess it's too big of an answer for this question, sorry